# grid center child div without text-align

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I use `display:grid` for my div container. Within this container I got some items that should keep their `text-align:left` but I want their parent being centered.

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: calc(50% - 50px) calc(50% - 50px);
  grid-gap: 50px;
}

.gridItem {
  max-width: 300px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">

  <div class="gridItem">
    <img src="url">
    <p>
      Item 1
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="gridItem">
    <img src="url">
    <p>
      Item 2
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="gridItem">
    <img src="url">
    <p>
      Item 3
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="gridItem">
    <img src="url">
    <p>
      Item 4
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

So I want to center `.gridItem` within the grid but I don't want to use `text-align:center` because the children of `.gridItem` should not get centered.

I tried `align-items: center` for `#grid` and `align-self:center` for `.gridItem` but this did not help.

How can I do achieve this?

Comment: try `margin:0 auto;`  in .gridItem

Comment: In css grid that should be `justify-items: center;`

Comment: I think both of you are right :)

Comment: please tell us if you could solve your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise adding a width (or max-width ) to the #grid, and maybe adding an outline, at least temporarily for testing. If the grid's width is 100% then the parent won't appear centered, and you will not see the effect of `margin:0 auto`  (which would center the grid). If after seeing the centered grid with the outline, you wish to widen the grid items to get a more 'centered' appearance, then do so.

See snippet

```css
body{
width:100%}

#grid {
  width: 70%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: calc(50% - 50px) calc(50% - 50px);
  grid-gap: 50px;
  margin:0 auto;
  outline: 1px solid #000000;
}

.gridItem {
  max-width: 300px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">

  <div class="gridItem">
    <img src="url">
    <p>
      Item 1
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="gridItem">
    <img src="url">
    <p>
      Item 2
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="gridItem">
    <img src="url">
    <p>
      Item 3
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="gridItem">
    <img src="url">
    <p>
      Item 4
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```